# Mass Copy and Rename files into same respective directories (CLI/PowerShell)

Tags: batch-file, copy, command-line-interface, rename, batch-rename

Say I have a file named `api-build009.jar` and it exists in multiple directories.

```
D:\InstallDir\subdir1\
D:\InstallDir\subdir2\subdir21\
D:\InstallDir\subdir3\
D:\InstallDir\subdir4\subdir41\
D:\InstallDir\subdir5\
D:\InstallDir\subdir6\subdir61\subdir62\
D:\InstallDir\subdir7\
D:\InstallDir\subdir8\
```

I want to backup (and thus rename) the file into the same respective directory as the original file. I want to perform this operation for all directories above (8, in this example), copying the original file and then rename it to `api-build009.jar.bak`.

```
D:\InstallDir\subdir1\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir2\subdir21\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir3\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir4\subdir41\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir5\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir6\subdir61\subdir62\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir7\api-build009.jar.bak
D:\InstallDir\subdir8\api-build009.jar.bak
```

How can I perform this process using Windows CLI or PowerShell?

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you write `a file` - sounds like the same file, and then you write backup `the file` in the same folder. Are these different versions or copies of the same file.
These scripts will copy the files to same name and location with `.bak` extension

Batch

```
@Echo off
PushD "D:\InstallDir"
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S api-build009.jar'
) Do Echo Copy "%%~fA" "%%~fA.bak"
Popd
```

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\InstallDir -File -Filter api-build009.jar|
  ForEach { Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "$($_.Fullname).bak" -whatif}
```

If the output looks ok remove the `echo` in the batch / `-whatif` in the script

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I was working on something similar but this looks a lot better. Can you refresh my memory -- what is the purpose of `~` here? What does `%%~fA` do exactly?

Comment: @user3621633 This is the for var modifier, see `for /?`. `~f` expands %%A to the fullname, same as `~dpnx` aka drive path name and extension.

Comment: Excellent. I appreciate the education. Thank you again for your help. This should do the trick, be it Batch or PowerShell. :)